# Когда мы делаем адаптив сайту, нужно делать адаптив для планшетов начиная от указанной ширины в МАКЕТЕ или приблизительной ширины планшетов?

Tags: html, css, figma

Имеется ввиду, если в макете дизайнера в фигме допустим вариант сайта для планшетов начинается с 764px ширины, то нужно начинать верстать вариант для планшетов (или телефонов) для этой ширины или же под примерный размер планшетов допутим 1000px

Comment: Зависит от дизайна и задумки автора. Невозможно дать точный ответ. Но как правило, делается макет на определенных брейкпоинтах (375 (телефон), 768 (маленький планшет, иногда пропускают), 992 (нормальный планшет), 1440 (ноутбук), 1920 (fullHD)), а промежуточные варианты или автоматически подгоняются при верстке, или уточняются уже по факту, если требуется.

Comment: Нужно верстать так, чтобы на 764px и других размерах, отображенных в мвкете выглядило "По макету", а на всех остальных экранах - "Адекватно". В Chrome есть все основные размеры от 320 до 1920 px. Я обычно беру 4 брейкпоинта - 320, 768, 992, 1920 + макетные размеры (1200 или 1440 на десктопе обычно) и стараюсь использовать относительные единицы при верстке.